# The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to debug my page using Facebook sharing debugger but I always get this error. It cannot access my image.

**The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.**

is it because of this in my .htaccess?

```
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: The message does not mean that it can not download the image, but that it does not even find an `og:image` meta tag in your HTML source code of the URL you are sharing.

Comment: Can you provide a URL that we can check?